# querying all related records of a parent dynamically

Tags: related-list

How to query dynamically all the related records or child of a parent using parentid
If you take for Account , Case,Partners,Opportunity,Note & Attachments etc...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have an Id in a variable `recordId`.

First fetch a map of keyPrefixes to its related SObjectType,

```
Map<String,Schema.SobjectType> keys = new Map<String,Schema.SobjectType>();
Map<String,Schema.SobjectType> describe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
for(String s:describe.keyset())
    keys.put(describe.get(s).getDescribe().getKeyPrefix(),describe.get(s));
```

Next, use your recordId to fetch the correct SObjectType and then fetch it's all children SObjectTypes.

```
Schema.SObjectType sobjectTypeObj = keys.get(recordId.substring(0,3));

Schema.DescribeSObjectResult obj = sobjectTypeObj.getDescribe();
for (Schema.ChildRelationship cr: obj.getChildRelationships()) 
{
  system.debug('Child Object Name:'+cr.getChildSObject());
}
```

Once you have all the child names, its pretty easy to for a nested SOQL of parent and child objects, like `Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name from Contacts) from Account`

Comment: `Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name from Contact) from Account` => `Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name from Contacts) from Account`

Answer (score 0):

You can query the related objects to the Account like this:

```
select (select Id from Cases),(select Id from Opportunities),(select Id from Notes),(select Id from Attachments) from Account
```

Comment: I don't want to write the child object names
Eg: Opportunities,Notes,Attachments

Comment: Then why do you explicitly state that in your original question?

Comment: i just edited my question.i have taken the sample related objects in the question,there will be some more childs also,, (......so on means more related objects.)

Answer (score 0):

The [DescribeSObjectResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) should help you here:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describe = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();

for (Schema.ChildRelationship child : describe.getChildRelationships()){

//do your logic

}
```

Comment: ,You are trying to show the related Objects,but the query is not about that.we have to show the related records of the parent using the parent id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all parents you need to use the describe the ParentId field.

```
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Schema.sObjectType.Attachment.fields.parentid;
System.debug('Relationship Name: ' + f.getRelationshipName());    

for(Schema.SObjectType reference : f.getReferenceTo()) {
    System.debug('Lookup reference object name: ' + reference.getDescribe().getName());
    System.debug('Lookup reference object label: ' + reference.getDescribe().getLabel());
}
```

Code segment that you can use all the objects where it is referenced and then you create a dynamic SOQL. which can be used in Database.Query();

The answers is lited [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51250/how-to-get-to-which-object-the-field-has-reference).

Let me know if it resolves.